# My javascript not compile on dist when I build my project on Vite

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, vite

I building my project on vite with multiple vanilla html pages.
My starter template is from "https://github.com/twbs/examples/tree/main"
All of my asset is on the src of this project.
My suspect is there is something wrong when I configure my vite.config.js to compile multiple html on the src.

here how I did on my vite.config.js

```
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  root: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
        about: resolve(__dirname, 'src/about.html'),
        contact: resolve(__dirname, 'src/contact.html'),
        service: resolve(__dirname, 'src/service.html'),
        
      },
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080
  }
})
```

this code only compile multiple html,css, and my photos.
How can I modify it to compile javascript on the dist when I build my project